# android : installed applications list

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to list the application which are installed in android device. I've successfully done this using this example. But, in this example they're extending Activity only. Now, i want  list the installed applications extends ListActivity. How can i do this? Please modify this example and give here Please. Thanks in Advance.[Getting Installed Applications](http://unknownerror.net/2011-07/android-to-get-the-installed-application-information-icon-name-version-number-package-37007)

Comment: They way you asked is most un-welcomed form of asking question on SO, this site user are mercy less they will tear down your question and your reputation for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, i want list the installed applications extends ListActivity. How can i do this?

That is not possible, sorry.

Comment: Ok, is there possible to display the all applications which are all in device. Like this example (Ex : - Android Device>Menu>Manage Applications>All)

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: Use `PackageManager` and `getInstalledPackages()`.

Comment: It shows only installed packages. But i need all the applications on device.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: Sorry, I meant `getInstalledApplications()`.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: There is a link in the upper-right corner of this page that is labeled "Ask Question". Use your mouse to click the link. Fill in the form. You did this before, to ask the question shown on this page. If you are saying that your account is now blocked on StackOverflow, then find another support system for your questions (e.g., the `android-developers` Google Group).

Comment: Finally, Is it Possible to fetch and list the received mails in our own layout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122184/using-content-provider-to-fetch-emails/7123052#7123052