# Using content provider to fetch emails

Tags: android, email, android-contentprovider

I need to fetch and list the received emails in my own layout listview.
Is this possible through Content Provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no documented and supported content providers for "received emails". "Email" is not really a part of the operating system (though there are a few lingering references to it from back in the 2006-2007 timeframe when there was no clear distinction between the OS, apps, and the SDK). There are probably hundreds of email clients, only a few of which might have such content providers, and probably no standards between them.

You will find some blog posts and other answers here on StackOverflow that point you to a Gmail content provider. This is an example of an undocumented and unsupported content provider. [It was also just closed off by Google](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/08/gmail-gone-risk-undocumented-apis.html).

You are welcome to write your own email client, store your own emails, and display them as you see fit, though.

Comment: Is there any other alternate way(Other than ContentProvider) to fetch and list the emails inbox in our own layout?

Comment: So we could only transfer the control to the core e-mail application to list out the inbox mails through the following code?

Intent intent = getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.email");
startActivity(intent);

Comment: @user905230: Even that technique assumes `com.android.email` exists and is in use, neither of which is necessarily true.

Comment: But if i use the above code, the control is alone transferred to that core email inbox layout.

Comment: @user905230: Correct, if it exists.

Comment: But once if i connect the device and run, at this time When I try to access the core database, I could not access even my other databases through DDMS tool. I'm afraid that it would lock my all other databases...

Comment: @user905230: You cannot access any databases on a device with DDMS.

Comment: ok,Thank you... In my DDMS tool,i cant build and explore any of my database files and its tables since there is not permission to access the table.How to overcome the read write permission in File explorer?  Is there any solution for it?

Comment: @user905230: This has nothing whatsoever to do with your original question. Please ask new questions using the Ask Question link, the same way you asked this question.